# Rename all project dependencies without renaming main artifact

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm building an assembly in Maven using a descriptor and I'm trying to simply do the following:

1. Include the main project artifact (JAR) without *any* renaming.
2. Include all project dependencies, renaming them.

Rename format:

```
${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.lib.${artifact.artifactId}.${artifact.extension}`
```

Currently, my assembly descriptor looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">

    <id>default</id>

    <formats>
        <format>tar.gz</format>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>

    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*:*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </dependencySet>
        <dependencySet>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <outputFileNameMapping>
                ${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.lib.${artifact.artifactId}.${artifact.extension}
            </outputFileNameMapping>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the main project artifact to land in the distribution. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess it has to do with your `<exclude>` pattern. Try to remove it and see if your project artifact ends up where it is supposed to. If yes, you'll have to modify the pattern somehow (maybe use `<includes>` instead).

Comment: I seem to remember that if you run mvn with `-X` the assembly plugin debug output should tell you what it's matching with each dependencySet.  I agree with Andrew, I'd try using `includes` instead of `excludes` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `<files>` block to include the project artifact itself separately:

```
<!-- Include the project artifact itself. -->
<files>
    <file>
        <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</source>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </file>
</files>

<!-- Include all dependent libraries. -->
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <outputFileNameMapping>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.lib.${artifact.artifactId}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

(For the `<source>` there may be a more correct expression than the one above, but finding a complete list of available Maven properties is difficult. If anyone knows it, feel free to edit!)

Lastly, as an aside, if any of your dependencies have classifiers you may want to consider adding `${dashClassifier?}` to your `<outputFileNameMapping>` somewhere, or else the classifier will be missing from the filename.